# Confusion related to Spectral radius of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-radius

Calculate the spectral radius of
$\begin{equation}A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1\\ 2 &1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
$

My understanding is spectral radius is maximum modulus of the largest eigenvalue of $A$

eigenvalues are $1+\sqrt2$ and $1-\sqrt2$

So, $\rho(A)=1+\sqrt2$

But in one research article $\rho(A)=\frac{1+\sqrt2}{2+\sqrt2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$

Can Someone catch my mistake?

Thank in advanced.

Comment: Which research article?

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2156438

Comment: Please see Page no 8(252) in which A^+N I have doubt.

Comment: I think it might be a typo because they're trying to prove that $\rho(M^\dagger N)<1$ and they have the correct value from it, which follows from $\rho(A^\dagger N)=1+\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @Derivative But He choose those matrix such that it follows that all four statements are equivalent. But For this particular example spectral radius of both $A^+N$ and $M^+N$ are not same.